# Python : the s language decoded using append

Tags: python

Input a sentence: Whasat doso yousou presefeser?
Output a sentence: What do you prefer?

At the moment only the p is changed by []. There are some mistakes with the code but I can not find it.

```
# input a sentence
text = input('Enter a text: ')

# create two variables
vowelgroup = []  
decoded_text = [] 

vowel = 'aeiou'

# loop through all letters of sentence
for i in text:
    if i != "vowel" and i != "s":
        decoded_text.append(i)
    if i == "vowel":
        vowelgroup.append(i)
    if i == "s":
        decoded_text.append(vowelgroup)

# unlist the decoded tekst to string
L = ''.join(map(str, decoded_text))

print(L)
```

Comment: "At the moment only the p is changed by []" ? Please put some effort and try to explain what is it you're trying to do. Counting on us figuring it out by ourselves is not a good idea...

Answer (score 0):

```
# input a sentence
text = input('Enter a text: ')

# create two variables
vowelgroup = []  
decoded_text = [] 

vowel = 'aeiou'

# loop through all letters of sentence
container = False
for i in text:
    if container:
        container = False
        continue
    if i != "vowel" and i != "s":
        decoded_text.append(i)
    if i == "vowel":
        vowelgroup.append(i)
    if i == "s":
        for j in vowelgroup:
          decoded_text.append(j)
        container = True

# unlist the decoded tekst to string
L = ''.join(map(str, decoded_text))

print(L)
```

Is this what you are aiming for? I don't get which among the letters beside an 's' will should be the trigger. In this case, once an 's' is scanned, the next character will automatically be skipped.

Comment: It is not correct. For example: Input : Pepeteper Pipipeper pipickeped Output with your code: Peter Pir cked  Correct output: Peter Piper picked

Comment: It won't be correct because your code only scans the character 's'. And your 's' is the trigger for you to concatenate the letters contained in `vowelgroup` to the `decoded_text` array. If you use 'p', no wonder it won't work. Please clarify all details and your sample inputs if possible so that we really know what we are working on.

Comment: It is s instead of p. And an example is stated above: Input : Pepeteper Pipipeper pipickeped     Output with your wrong code: Peter Pir cked Correct output: Peter Piper picked

Answer (score 0):

We iterate through the sentence letter by letter i. When the first letter i is not a vowel (a consonant) we store it in our decoded text variable. We repeat till when we encounter a vowel we save this vowel letter(s) in the vowel group till we encounter a 's' and we want to pass this vowelgroup to the decoded tekst instead of the 's'. Than we continue till we encounter again a non vowel (consonant) letter which will be added again to the decoded tekst and so on and on for each letter i.

```
text = input('Enter a text: ')


vowelgroup = []  
decoded_text = [] 

vowel = 'aeiou'

for i in text:
    if i != 'vowel':
        decoded_text.append(i)
    if i == 'vowel':
        vowelgroup.append(i)
    if i == 's':
        decoded_text.append(vowelgroup)

L = ''.join(map(str, decoded_text))

print(L)
```